# Get roles and user from webcontainer in Play framework

Tags: playframework, single-sign-on, playframework-2.3, websphere-liberty

I am unable to get the roles for users in play from my web-container.

In short, this is the situation

- We are using Websphere Liberty Profile (WPL) so that it will be possible to have SSO to other IBM-products.
- The application is based on play framework.
- The roles for the user is defined in the realm that is specified in WPL.
- `play2war` is used, to be able to put the web application in our web-container (WPL)

I have tried to use play-pac4j (`play-pac4j_java` and `pac4j-http`) to get the users profile (with `JavaController.getUserProfile()`) but I get null when calling that method in my controller that extends `JavaController`. Maybe I am just using `pac4j` wrong some how.

I use

- Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.5
- Play Framework (2.3.8)
- Play2war (`play2-war-plugin` 1.3-beta3)
- pac4j  (`play-pac4j_java`, 1.3.0; `pac4j-http`, 1.6.0)

What can I do to get the users name and roles belonging to that user under these circumstances?

I don't have to use `pac4j`, although I think it would be a nice to use a library for this purpose (and it looks easy to get started with).

I have created a filter that got the user principal, and planned to put that in a ThreadLocal and read from that later. I put that design on shelf because I learned that play uses asynchronous calls, and I were not sure on how well that plays with ThreadLocal.

Any input on this?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look a the demo: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo? The user profile is retrieved after a successful authentication...

Comment: Is the profile retrieved via another call to the identity provider?  If so, does the response include the roles, if available?

Comment: In fact, pac4j is made to be an easy abstraction: so it can be another call or during the credentials validation, it's hidden for you. Roles and permissions can be retrieved from the identity provider, but they must at least made available in the user profile using an `AuthorizationGenerator`:  https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-core/src/main/java/org/pac4j/core/authorization/AuthorizationGenerator.java (example: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-core/src/main/java/org/pac4j/core/authorization/DefaultRolesPermissionsAuthorizationGenerator.java)